# Gridview scroll by keeping paging fixed

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I have a `asp:Gridview` that has a large datasource of some 600 rows. The gridview has been paged to show 100 rows per page. I need to add a scroll limiting the height of the gridview to `500px`

I have done that using

```
.fixed-height
{
    max-height : 500px;
    overflow-y : scroll;
}
```

on an outer `div`.

The issue is that the page selector is part of the grid view table and hence
is at the end of the scroll. Is there any way to fix the position of the last `tr` so that it is outside the scroll?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-vertical-scrollbar-to-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Comment: that does not talk about paging. does it manage the paging issue that I mentioned?

Comment: can you give a screenshot of your page how it looking ? so that we can check accordingly. Also it would be great if some more related code is shared